# Clojure: (with-out-str (doc catch)) returns ""

Tags: clojure

I wonder why this is.
`finally` and `&` also behave in this way.
Which other Clojure symbols have this behavior and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that you have stumbled across a bug in Clojure's implementation of `doc` that affects `&`, `catch`, and `finally`.  In the current `doc` implementation, these three are treated specially, and the associated expression appears to be missing a syntax quote.

Following is a mod to doc that adds the syntax quote and appears to work as intended.  This function must be placed in the `clojure.repl` namespace.

```
(defmacro doc2
  [name]
  (if-let [special-name ('{& fn, catch try, finally, try} name)]
    `(#'print-doc (#'special-doc '~special-name))
    (cond
     (special-doc-map name) `(#'print-doc (#'special-doc '~name))
     (find-ns name) `(#'print-doc (#'namespace-doc (find-ns '~name)))
     (resolve name) `(#'print-doc (meta (var ~name))))))
```

`(doc catch)` => { prints `try` doc and returns nil }

`(doc2 catch)` => { prints `try` doc and returns nil }

`(with-out-str (doc catch))` => { prints `try` doc and returns `""` }

`(with-out-str (doc2 catch))` => `"-------------------------\ntry\n  (try expr* catch-clause* finally-clause?)\nSpecial Form\n  catch-clause => (catch classname name expr*)\n  finally-clause => (finally expr*)\n\n  Catches and handles Java exceptions.\n\n  Please see http://clojure.org/special_forms#try\n"`

I'll chase this down on the Clojure bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect them to be so plainly in definition of `doc`.